# how to reset viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, stopwatch

How can i reset my stopwatch in swift? this is my code

```
@IBAction func resetButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewWillAppear(Bool)
}
@IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {
    print(stopwatch.elapsedTime)
    stopwatch.stop()
}
```

Comment: There is not much in your question that describes an actual problem. So we can't help you. I can tell you never to call `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` yourself. They are called when the VC loads and appears. They are never called directly by you.

Comment: Can you share what type of object `stopwatch` is?
As @RMenke commented, you shouldn't ever call `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` yourself. Instead, you should reset any objects that need to be reinitialized.
For example, if stopwatch is of type `Chrono`, in your resetButton method you could write something like
`stopwatch = Chrono()` to recreate the object and start fresh.